# Opmap Based Linear regulator

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, analog, power-electronics, ldo

I am designing an opamp based linear regulator for educational purpose.Please find the attached image.
[image]

I know that due to negative feedback voltage at the both terminals of the opamp will be same and is equal to Vref .Here it is 1.25V and Vout=Vref(1+R2/R1) and I obtained the proper 2.5V at output.

Now I removed the refernce and Vin(5V) is directly connected to Opamps non inverting terminal.
[image]
At this time the output obtained is 5V only as per the equation it shoud be 10V.May I know why
I am not getting 10V at output.Please tell me where I went wrong in understanding the circuit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May I know why I am not getting 10V at output.

You are not getting anything higher than 5 volts at the output because although the op-amp is powered from a positive supply of 15 volts, its output is clamped by the now forward biased base-collector region of Q1. See below and the little diode symbol I've added in red; it will limit U1's output to about 5.7 volts and, of course, that becomes about 5 volts at the emitter because both PN junctions in Q1 are forward biased: -

[image]

If you disconnected the collector from the circuit you should then see 10 volts at the output but, it's not much of a power regulator like this of course. If the 5 volts at the input (Vin) were sourced from a bridge rectifier (as per many supplies) then the bridge rectifier would get reversed biased due to the action of the red diode and the op-amp output would be able to lift the collector voltage with the outcome being that emitter would become 10 volts and hit the regulation target.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Here still negative feedback exixts,but may I know why opamp is not able to make it's both input equal.

Comment: The op-amp output is prevented from rising to 10.7 volts due to the internal collector-emitter diode becoming forward biased and clamping the collector to about 5.7 volts thus the emitter is about 5 volts also. Try disconnecting the collector and see how it will come into regulation.

Comment: Perfect answer , thanks so much.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, \$V_{IN}\$ is 5V. \$V_{OUT}\$ will never be more than \$V_{IN}\$ in your circuit.

Answer (score 1):

For the second circuit, change the input V4 to 6 V.  The output probably will go to 6 V.  this is *not* because the circuit is functioning at unity bain.  It is because the circuit output is saturated.

To see what is going on, delete U2 and replace it with a 1.2K resistor to GND. Leave R3 in place.  Now the opamp input is approx 1 V, and the output should go to 2 V.